# Rewrite URL based on HTTP_HOST

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I want users can access the page via intranet and internet.

If users access the page via intranet, they can typing intranet IP of server on their browser address bar to **`192.168.x.x`**.

But when users access the page via internet, they can typing public IP of server, I will rewrite the URL to public IP of server.

I have tried this, but I get the page **not properly redirected**.

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /mypath/
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !(.*)/$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}        !192.168.0.1
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          http://<public.ip.of.server>/mypath/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}        !<public.ip.of.server>
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          http://192.168.0.1/mypath/$1/   [L,R=301]
```

I have tried this too, but I get the page **500 internal server error**.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == '192.168.0.1'">
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /mypath/
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !(.*)/$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          http://192.168.0.1/mypath/$1/   [L,R=301]
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'public.ip.of.server'">
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /mypath/
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !(.*)/$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          http://<public.ip.of.server>/mypath/$1/ [L,R=301]
</If>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's a typo in the second block: you have `HTPP` twice instead of `HTTP`

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Comment: @TomSmilack I'm sorry for typo, actually I have the right HTTP_HOST on my htaccess. I'll fix my code here.

Comment: @JonLin I'm using Apache 2.2.3

Comment: Your ancient version of Apache has known security issues... Hope the script kiddies don't find you.

Comment: Thanks for warning. I actually use the apache from Centos 5.8 distribution. I will update it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using Apache 2.2.3

The [`<If>` Directive is part of Apache 2.4's core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if). Those directives will cause a 500 server error if you put them in 2.2. It's not clear at all what you're trying to do, but you can replace the `<If>` blocks with a simple `RewriteCond`.

The important concept here is that `RewriteCond`s **only apply to the immediately following** `RewriteRule` directive, they won't apply to any other ones, only just that single one. So you need to duplicate conditions if you need them to be applied to multiple rules.

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /mypath/

RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST} ^192.168.0.1$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !(.*)/$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          http://192.168.0.1/mypath/$1/   [L,R=301]

RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST} ^public.ip.of.server$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !(.*)/$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          http://<public.ip.of.server>/mypath/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

But you can just get rid of all of that because you can redirect without using the `http://hostname` bit:

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !(.*)/$
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_METHOD}   GET
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$  /mypath/$1/   [L,R=301]
```

And that would accomplish the above for any host.

Comment: Shame on me. I saw wrong documentation :lol: Thanks for correcting it.
I've tried both, first code works. But second one does not work. I do not know why. Thank you very much.